# Swift add all elements from array together

Tags: ios, arrays, function, swift

I have an array of numbers and I want to iterate through all of the elements in that array and add together all of the integers. Here is the function I have so far:

```
func addTogether(array:Array<Int>, divide:Int) -> Int
{
    var a = 0

    while a < array.count
    {

    }

    return 0
}
```

I know that I'm probably going to have to do this inside of the while loop. Can anyone give me some guidance as to where to go from here? Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No loop needed. Use `reduce`, like this:

```
let sum = array.reduce(0,+)
```

Comment: While this is also a loop technically it still *looks* much nicer :-)

Comment: @Patru "This is also a loop" I was afraid someone would point that out. :)

Comment: Still i consider it a nice piece of syntax, even beats Rubys `#inject` (though only by  `:` ;-)

Comment: @Patru maybe, but `array.reduce(:+)` does the same in Ruby :)

Comment: @FeifanZ You are probably right for the number of characters, but semantically the `:` is a weird "special case" where a symbol is randomly interpreted as a method in a certain case. This is much less so in Swift.

Comment: Is **reduce** is a property?